# Why does passing a const std::string& to a constructor not allow you to bind it to a const std::string& member variable in the initialiser list?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, reference, constants

Ok, I've got a strange occurrence here. (At least I believe it's strange but I could be making a fundamental mistake)

So, I've got a constructor like so:

```
Module(const std::string& name) : m_name(name)
        {
            std::cout<<"Module String Constructor"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Constructed with name "<<m_name<<std::endl;
        }
```

The member variable m_name looks like this:

```
 const std::string& m_name;
```

I have validated the constructor gets called and m_name is set correctly with those console outputs.

However, when I attempt to retrieve the name at some point in the future using:

```
 inline const std::string& GetName()
        {
            return m_name;
        }
```

I get an empty object with Zero length.

I can get it working correctly by removing the *const* and *&* specifiers from the member variable

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems you pass a temporary objuect as for example a string literal to the constructor. As result the program has undefined behavior

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yep, looks like it. Can we see the code that contructs the module?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4369853/1283466

Comment: You need to be careful working with pointers and references - they can easily become dangled so you need to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks @OpenKastle that was exactly the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ passing a string literal instead of a const std::string&?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369807/c-passing-a-string-literal-instead-of-a-const-stdstring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but then I can't call the constructor with a string literal.

If you initialize the object from a string literal, a temporary `std::string` will be used to pass to the constructor of `Module`. The temporary could be bound to lvalue-reference-to-const, but it will be destroyed after the whole expression immediately, after that the member reference `m_name` becomes dangled. Getting it from `Module::GetName()` and dereference on it leads to UB.

You can use a named variable instead to initialize the object; and you still need to notice the lifetime of the variable. Or stop using the member reference.

Comment: Could you please add the solution (how to write the constructor) to solve this and have a perfect answer?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois I added. I'm not sure about OP's intent, under the current type of parameter and data member I can't think of better one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!